# Cannot see "Mule--> Generate Flows" option on right clicking Mule project in Anypoint studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, raml

I have imported RAML files into mule project in Anypoint studio (src/main/api). I do not see the "Mule -> Generate Flows" option when I right click on the RAML file. It was apparing earlier. I have attached screenshot here.

[anypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJgzJ.png)

Comment: Can you try re-importing it as a mule project? Also what version of mule are you using and studio?

Comment: re-imported but same issue. I'm using mule 3.x and Anypoint studio 6.5 @RyanCarter

Answer (score 2):

Stolen from: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/45323/depoly-to-cloud-option-is-not-visible-in-the-anypo.html

You are using an incorrect View:

Current View is Project Explorer

Expected View is Package Explorer

Therefore open it by accessing menu: Window >> Show View >> Package Explorer

Comment: that's correct, thanks a lot @utechtzs! unfortunately couldnt upvote since I do not have enough reputation points..

Comment: You can still accept the answer, using the tick check mark  next to the question @rahulreddy